# bitcoin is not showing the correct balance after reusing an address

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, balance, sparrow-wallet

(i only reused because the first one was a test) Bitcoin core gui is showing a balance lower than the amount on sparrow. Sparrow is connected through my node and showing the correct amounts so I know my node is not messed up. Here's what I think is wrong but I don't know how to fix it: I send a small amount of bitcoin to an address. Then sent a larger amount to that address after I was sure that it was safe to send to it. The second spend went through and is properly displayed on sparrow, but the balance I sent is now not showing up on bitcoin core. How can I get bitcoin core to display it properly? I think it is because of the address reuse thing because that is the amount that is missing on bitcoin core and also chat gtp said that it could be a reason for issues. I don't know how to fix this. Is there even a way? I was planning on sending more to this same address because I am switching from a singlesig to a multisig and like to reuse an address when moving larger funds. but i dont like that it doesn't show up in bitcoin core

Comment: Well I spent the transaction that I suspected to be missing from the bitcoin core balance to get it to a different address. It fixed it but then when I did some more transactions it got messed up again and now I have no idea how bitcoin core is adding up its balance. Sparrow seems to work normal even though it's connected though by node but the balance on core is still off

Answer (score 0):

> **chat gtp said that [address reuse] could be a reason for issues.**

I wouldn't rely on Chat GPT because [Chat GPT also says that 2+2=5](https://twitter.com/random_walker/status/1600336556425826304) and [doesn't understand what the heck it is doing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38220/why-is-chatgpt-bad-at-math). Chat GPT is a *language model* that takes any old nonsense and converts it to a superficially plausible grammatical paragraph or two.

As https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt says

> ChatGPT sometimes writes plausible-sounding but incorrect or nonsensical answers.

I suspect that "sometimes" may mean "often".

Address reuse was the norm when Bitcoin Core was first written, I am sure that address reuse does not cause the issues you describe.

---

> **How can I get bitcoin core to display [the balance I expect] properly?**

I would make sure Bitcoin Core is fully synchronised. There is an icon at bottom right of its window that tells you if it is synchronised or catching up etc.

I would check that the transaction corresponding to the missing amount is a confirmed transaction (e.g. using a blockchain explorer)

Comment: I've done the things like checking block explorers and the transaction are going through normally. I should also note that bitcoin core shows the transaction. (but sometimes not the amounts of the transactions, weird) and remember that sparrow is working fine and normally even though it is getting all of its information from my node.